# How to create a Netlify Deploy Preview with cache clear?

Tags: caching, node-modules, netlify

With my Netlify site I can manually choose to trigger a deployment on my `master` branch and opt to clear the cache.

[image]

However I cannot find a way of doing this with my **Deploy Preview** branch.

I have made an npm package version change and Deploy Preview isn't picking up on my change. Instead it's restoring the existing node_modules:

[image]

How can I manually trigger a deployment of Deploy Preview with cache clear, or disable the restoration of `node_modules` when rebuilding a Deploy Preview branch?

Comment: I would also like to do this since I frequently encounter deploy errors when caching is used.

Comment: Note that this is now possible by choosing the `Clear cache and deploy site` option on a site's Deploys page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for you to trigger a cache-cleared deploy preview, though Netlify's helpdesk can for you.

However, that shouldn't be needed.  We intend to re-run `npm install` or `yarn install` if the checksum on `/package.json` or `/yarn.lock` changes:

https://github.com/netlify/build-image/blob/master/run-build-functions.sh#L54

How did you change the package version?